# Can I change the bullet image that is used in the Content Query Web Part?

Tags: content-query-web-part

Is it possible to change the bullet image in the content query web part from within the Content Query Tool Part window that opens when you select Edit Web Part?

If not is it a good suggestion to use JQuery/CSS to replace the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the css that what worked for me,

```
.bullet
{
    background : url('../../../Style Library/MyProject/Images/bullet1.gif') no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your quick question deserves a quick answer: Yes!

Bullet images are defined in CSS, so you can override the formatting by adding your own CSS for the elements you want to change.

Comment: apologies for the short question, I intended to add to it straight away but got distracted by a bigger problem and then hunger

Comment: ill take this opportunity to stipulate: never do SharePoint on an empty stomech! :-) +1 for feeding a hungry coder with a short answer :p

Comment: No worries, gotsp. There was enough there for me to give an answer. Hopefully it's an answer you can use!